# Why does git think that I am Jim Weirich?

Tags: git

I'm following along on the git immersion tutorial. 
Since I knew the basics I started from lab_15 in the repos. I'm able to follow along the tutorial just fine but all my commits show up as being made by `Jim Weirich`.

```
 ~/D/g/g/r/lab_15> git log -4
commit d53e9e4a6539f3fe568dbbbfcf50b8556fd0ba1f
Author: Jim Weirich <jim (at) neo.com>
Date:   Sun Apr 20 00:11:51 2014 +0530

    Added Author

commit 1f7ec5eaa8f37c2770dae3b984c55a1531fcc9e7
Author: Jim Weirich <jim (at) neo.com>
Date:   Sat Apr 13 15:20:42 2013 -0400

    Added a comment
```

Since the timestamp show's the last commit being done only a few minutes back I'm positive that this wasn't done by Jim.

I have correctly set up my user and email as specified in lab_01

```
~/D/g/g/r/lab_15> git config --global user.name
Nikhil Bhardwaj
```

Why is git confusing me with `Jim`?

I've downloaded the tutorial from [here](http://gitimmersion.com/git_tutorial.zip) (zip file).

Comment: What's your not-global config? What commands have you executed?

Comment: Would this link be better than the .zip link you provided: http://gitimmersion.com/lab_15.html ? Also see http://gitimmersion.com/lab_10.html that you skipped which mentions [Jim Weirich](https://github.com/jimweirich) who sadly [has passed](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jim_Weirich).

Comment: Oh, I didn't know that he had passed. May he Rest in Peace.

Comment: @AD7six I didn't execute any other commands. In the link that I have mentioned I just switched to the repos/lab_15 directory which was a git repo already. Looks like the original authors settings were also there, had I not downloaded the zip file and used git checkout repo would this have happened?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Maybe you've changed your name locally. Every git repository has his own configuration which override the global configuration.

Check it with

```
git config user.name
git config user.email
```

You can change it easily with

```
git config user.name Nikhil Bhardwaj
git config user.email nikhil@example.com
```

Comment: Right, this fixes it. Though my last commit still shows Jim's name but I understand this. The local settings take precedence over the global settings.